# how to access two same application simultaneously in testcomplete?

Tags: automated-tests, testcomplete

I need to access two visual studio 2010 application simultaneous. For example, first VS action is open one created project and run this project. I created namemapping path for this VS and done this action. need to do same action in second VS, but problem is, created NM path is identified first Visual studio window. Please find the attached image for this issue.
Can anyone help, how to access two VS application at same time?

[image: Image for second VS window mapped name also shown as first VS mapped name]

[image: Image for first VS window mapped name]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the **devenv** proces by two properties: **ProcessName** and **Index**. For the Index property, use a project variable as a value. During the test, set the value of this project variable to 1 or 2 depending on with which exactly instance of Visual Studio you want to work and call the RefreshMappingInfo method for the mapping name of the VS process object (**VisualStudio** on your images). So, using this approach you will apply the mapping tree to the process instance you want to work right now.